# Alter sheet within Google spreadsheet without making it active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with multiple sheets. I want to initiate a script in one of the sheets that reads/writes values in the other sheets without making the other sheets active. I found that if I set the other sheets active during the operation of the script, the other sheets are then displayed to the user. Is there a way to perform operations on the other sheets without the display changing?

I am giving you the relevant part of the function. I want to read and write values in a few sheets within a spreadsheet without the display switching to those sheets.

```
/*** Calculate the ROI for each sheet ***/ 
function calcRoi(sheetNumber) {
  var total = 0;
  var cellLocation = "";
  var rowValue = 0;
  var cellValue = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var tempCellValue = 0;
  var roi = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  activeSheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[sheetNumber]);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I am giving you the relevant part of the function. I want to read and write values in a few sheets within a spreadsheet without the display switching to those sheets.

/*** Calculate the ROI for each sheet   ***/  
function calcRoi(sheetNumber) {
  
  var total = 0;
  var cellLocation = "";
  var rowValue = 0;
  var cellValue = 0;
  var count = 0;
  var tempCellValue = 0;
  var roi = 0;
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  activeSheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[sheetNumber]);

Answer (score 2):

Do not use

```
activeSheet = ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[sheetNumber]);
```

Instead use

```
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
sheets[sheetNumber].getRange("Range Here").getValue();
sheets[sheetNumber].getRange("Range Here").setValue("Value");
```

Setting a range active is needed only when you want to make that range show on the screen.